# Filter for rows using a set of non unique ID's

Tags: mysql, database

For example:
*Say I'm trying to select **media** with **tag_id**'s of **4**,**15** and **9** from the table **mediaTable***
[image]
I want it so I only get **film1** but, if I write the statement like this:
`SELECT media FROM mediaTable WHERE tag_id = 15 OR tag_id = 4 OR tag_id=9`
I get both **film1** and **book1**  and, if I write it with **AND** instead of **OR** I don't actually get anything because I believe it is looking for 3 different **tag_id** columns with the respective **tag_id**'s in one record.
Using the **IN** statement got me in the exact same position as the **OR** statement and, with that, I have no more idea except that I may be able to use **IF()**, but I am unsure on how this would be applied.

The results that I am looking for is just **film1**

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can put what should the result be!

Comment: Can you describe in words what exactly you are looking for? I mean: Given your table, how would you explain to me which rows you want to have (or not have). If you say "I want entries with tag 4,15 or 9", there is no reason why you should not get 6 rows in return, including both film1 and book1 - so there must be some additional critera.

Comment: In the MySQL result I want the **media** cell which matches with all 3 **tag_id**'s so, **film1** as  **tag_id**'s **15**,**4** and **9** are found along side **film1** in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions, but the shortest is probably

```
select media 
from mediaTable 
where tag_id = 15 OR tag_id = 4 OR tag_id=9 
group by media 
having count(distinct tag_id) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! With a bit of editing in PHP, this'll do exactly what I need it to do!